# HTML: <input> Cannot seem to use "pattern=", and "list=" at the same time?

Tags: html, regex, validation, html-datalist

I am providing an input field for submission for users. One of which is a URL. I would like to restrict the URLs allowed as seen below:

```
        <input name="source" type="url" pattern="https://www.youtube.com/(.+)|https://www.vimeo.com/(.+)|https://open.spotify.com/(.+)|https://www.soundcloud.com/(.+)|https://www.deezer.com/(.+)" placeholder="{$lng->source_place}" value="{$source}">
```

This works fine. I also have another approach where the field provides a drop-down menu instead to show which URLs are recommended for submission:

```
        <input name="source" type="url" list="defaultURLs">
                        <datalist id="defaultURLs">
                          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.vimeo.com/">
                          <option value="https://open.spotify.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.soundcloud.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.deezer.com/">
                        </datalist>
```

This also works fine by itself, however does not prevent user from submitting other URLs.

I've tried to combine the two so that the recommended sites are provided in a dropdown menu and those choices are enforced. So, theoretically something like this:

```
<input name="source" type="url" list="defaultURLs" pattern="https://www.youtube.com/(.+)|https://www.vimeo.com/(.+)|https://open.spotify.com/(.+)|https://www.soundcloud.com/(.+)|https://www.deezer.com/(.+)|http://bbcsfx.acropolis.org.uk/(.+)|https://soundbible.com/(.+)" placeholder="URLs" value="{$source}">
                        <datalist id="defaultURLs">
                          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.vimeo.com/">
                          <option value="https://open.spotify.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.soundcloud.com/">
                          <option value="https://www.deezer.com/">
                        </datalist>
```

However only the "pattern=" is enforced with no dropdown menu visible.

I thought I read somewhere (and stupidly cannot find the link again) that this was not possible, but within the same thread someone had found a workaround.

Any thoughts/inputs appreciated

Comment: It's curious. It works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9rdp8c3/3/)

Comment: [It work everywhere](https://jsfiddle.net/g9rdp8c3/5/), just add some CSS to show what is valid and what is invalid.